# String formatting on SQL insert using dict

Tags: python, mysql

The following is how I usually add in params in `MySQLdb`:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO main_territory (code, name) VALUES (%s, %s)', (item[0], item[1]))
```

Is there a way to make the string formatting more intuitive? For example, if I have 50 args in the `INSERT`. Something like:

```
cursor.execute('''INSET INTO main_territory (code, name) VALUES ({code}, {name})''',
                  {code=item[0], name=item[1}
               )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the database driver. Usually, if positional arguments (`%s`) are supported, then named arguments could be to, using the `%(name)s` format:

```
cursor.execute(
    '''INSERT INTO main_territory (code, name) VALUES (%(code)s, %(name)s)''',
    {'code': item[0], 'name': item[1]})
```

The parameter values then are passed in as a dictionary.

The most commonly used MySQL database adapter, [MySQLdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python) supports this style.

Other database adapters use `?` and `:name` as the positional and named arguments; you can query the style used with the [`paramstyle` attribute](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) on the module:

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> MySQLdb.paramstyle
'format'
```

but because most drivers support both positional and named styles, they usually just name one (`'format'` or `'qmark'`) while also supporting the named variants. Always consult the documentation to verify this.

Comment: Thanks, for clarification, I'm using `MySQLdb`.

Comment: @David542: then you can use that style.